# Prove that $\lim _{n\to \infty \:}\left(\sqrt{n^2+3}-\sqrt{n^2+1}\right)=0$

Tags: calculus

Prove that $\lim _{n\to \infty \:}\left(\sqrt{n^2+3}-\sqrt{n^2+1}\right)=0$. I’m new to the subject and the square roots are throwing me a bit off.

Comment: For any positive $a$, I think we have $n^2+1<(n+a)^2$ for large enough $n$. Same for $n^2+3$.

Answer (score 2):

You first have to multiply the top and bottom by the conjuage, which is $\sqrt{n^2+3} + \sqrt{n^2+1}$.

So you get $$\dfrac{(\sqrt{n^2+3}-\sqrt{n^2+1})(\sqrt{n^2+3}+\sqrt{n^2+1})}{\sqrt{n^2+3}+\sqrt{n^2+1}} = \dfrac{n^2+3 - (n^2+1)}{\sqrt{n^2+3} + \sqrt{n^2+1}} = \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{n^2+3} + \sqrt{n^2+1}}$$

Clearly, the $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ of this expression $ = 0$.

Comment: I think it will be $\frac{2}{\sqrt{n^2+3}+\sqrt{n^2+1}}$

Comment: Oops. Thanks for that error!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $$\sqrt{n^2+3}-\sqrt{n^2+1}=\dfrac{(\sqrt{n^2+3}-\sqrt{n^2+1})(\sqrt{n^2+3}+\sqrt{n^2+1})}{\sqrt{n^2+3}+\sqrt{n^2+1}}$$

Answer (score 0):

You can compute
\begin{align}\\
\lim_{x\to0^+}\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}+3}-\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}+1}
&=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{(\sqrt{1+3x^2}-1)-(\sqrt{1+x^2}-1)}{x} \\
&=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{(\sqrt{1+3x^2}-1)}{x}-\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(\sqrt{1+x^2}-1)}{x} \\
\end{align}
and you recognize the derivatives of $f(x)=\sqrt{1+3x^2}$ and $g(x)=\sqrt{1+x^2}$ at $0$, which are both $0$.